# Using Mockito Test case failed

Tags: junit, mockito

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) //Class cannot be resolved to a type //@SpringBootTest public class MbankingApplicationTest {

    @Mock  CanmbTransactionDao dataServiceMock;
    @Mock  CanmbBaseDao baseDao;
    @InjectMocks  CanmbTransactionServiceImpl businessImpl;
    @Autowired  OminiController controller;
    Customer customer;
    @Test public void test() {
        Customer cust= new Customer();
        cust.setMbnumber("+919990176197");
        cust.setDeviceid("abcdef");
        UserProfileMaster profile = new UserProfileMaster();
        profile.setChkflag(22);
        profile.setStatus("ACTIVE");
        cust.setUserProfile(profile);
        cust.setMpin("123456");
        cust.setMpinsalt("12345");
        when(dataServiceMock.getUserMbAndDevice("+919990176197", "abcdef")).thenReturn(cust);
        this.customer = cust;
        assertEquals(cust, businessImpl.getUserMbAndDevice("+919990176197", "abcdef"));
    }

    @Test public void testMpin() {
        Customer cust = new Customer();
        cust.setMbnumber("+919990176197");
        cust.setDeviceid("abcdef");
        UserProfileMaster profile = new UserProfileMaster();    profile.setChkflag(22);
        profile.setStatus("ACTIVE");
        cust.setUserProfile(profile);
        cust.setMpin("d150cb2c64171a95eb3fa1bbf2ea786aef16b04d389a1ac67a52c75e95f61e66");
        cust.setMpinsalt("12345");

        when(dataServiceMock.getUserMbAndDevice("+919990176197", "abcdef")).thenReturn(cust);

        //assertEquals(cust, businessImpl.getUserMbAndDevice("+919990176197", "abcdef"));
        MBSOMNIIntegration reqData = new MBSOMNIIntegration();
        reqData.setMbnumber("+919990176197");
        reqData.setDeviceid("abcdef");
        reqData.setMpin("123456");

        OMNIIntegration omni=new OMNIIntegration();

        // businessImpl.validateOmniMpin(reqData, omni, "123");
        ResponseData data= new ResponseData();
        Map<String,String> ominiMap= new HashMap<>();
        ominiMap.put("Msg", "verified");        ominiMap.put("statusCode", "0");
        data.setStatusCode(0);
        data.setTid("");
        data.setData(ominiMap);
        when(businessImpl.validateOmniMpin(reqData, omni, "123")).thenReturn(data);
        assertEquals(data,businessImpl.validateOmniMpin(reqData, omni, "123"));
    }
```

> Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.835 sec
>     <<< FAILURE! - in com.npst.mb.MbankingApplicationTest testMpin(com.npst.mb.MbankingApplicationTest) Time elapsed: 0.823 sec
>     <<< FAILURE! java.lang.AssertionError: expected: com.npst.mb.pojo.ResponseData but was: com.npst.mb.pojo.ResponseData at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89) at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:835) at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:120) at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:146) at com.npst.mb.MbankingApplicationTest.testMpin(MbankingApplicationTest.java:93)

Results:

Failed tests: MbankingApplicationTest.testMpin:93 expected: com.npst.mb.pojo.ResponseData but was: com.npst.mb.pojo.ResponseData

Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 12.493 s [INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-17T14:57:43+05:30 [INFO] Final Memory: 36M/346M [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project CapexMbankingPhase2: There are test failures. [ERROR] [ERROR] Please refer to /home/npstx/raj/Canara Projects/MBS_APP_OMNI/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results. [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Comment: You should edit your question into something more readable. In its current state, your question is very difficult to understand.

Comment: please give some context and ask an actual question, don't just throw some code and some errors. Also, please fix the formatting of the second part. I've edited your post to make the code readable and to improve the first message; it's not quite clear what the seconde one should be formatted like